# Angular 8: How avoid duplicate logic for parent and child

Tags: angular, typescript

I have common requests in parent controller. Also I read router params for requests.
For childs I have different requests but I need to read the same parameters from router - As a results I am getting duplicate code.

For parent and children :

```
this.param1 = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param1');
this.param2 = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param2');
```

And the same init for param1 and param2.

Use children via

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Connection between parent and children via Services.

There is better way to avoid this? Move reading of params to Service and subscribe on it? But I still have init of variable. Or maybe create common class and add it to implements for parent and child?

Comment: route: ActivatedRoute is already a service

Comment: @Ininiv Cause it is service :) Problem is not only in router. Parent and child use the same logic for different requests - I just want to avoid duplicate code

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either like you said create a service and process the params logic there, then just import the service and use the variable with the param value. Or you could use event emitter to pass values from parent to children, for more information about event emitter check the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)